# Why else block is executed even though if condition is true?

Tags: javascript, object

I was practicing some JavaScript on Codeacademy few minutes ago and I found something confusing. Here is the code:

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
};
friends.steve = {
  firstName: "Steve",
  lastName: "Jobs",
  number: "(408) 555-5555",
  address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
};

var list = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
};

var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends) {
    if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
      console.log(friends[prop]);
      return friends[prop];
    }
    else {
      return  "contact not found";
    }
  }
};

list(friends);
search("Steve");
```

The problem is that when I pass the string "Steve" as an arg in the search function, it returns the condition "Contact not found" while when I pass the string "Bill" as an arg in the same search function, it displays the contact information.

How is that possible? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, in the first iteration of the loop, the `prop` value is something else apart from `Steve`. So, the `if` condition fails, reaches the `else` part and returns `contact not found` immediately.

But, you should return `not found` message only when none of the objects's `firstName` matches, like this

```
function search(name) {
  for (var prop in friends) {
    if (friends[prop].firstName === name) {
      return friends[prop];
    }
  }
  return "contact not found";
};
```

Comment: Thank you but why does it work when I pass the "Bill" string instead of "Steve"?

Comment: @AhmedMagdy `Bill` is the first key returned when the `friends` object is iterated. You can use `console.log` inside the `for` loop to confirm this.

Answer (score 4):

```
else {
  return  "contact not found";
}
```

You're returning not found as soon as you find a contact that doesn't match.

You shouldn't give up until you run out of items.